# Unwanted question marks using beamer, tikz and mindmaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

I'm trying to use the `mindmaps` library inside a `beamer` presentation. After typesetting, I get questions marks that I didn't include. I just don't know where they come from. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to avoid it? These are my MWE and the output slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\title{Presentation}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
￼\frametitle{Basic concepts}
￼￼￼￼
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
  \node [concept]                 {Root concept};
  \node [extra concept] at (10,0) {extra concept};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see it with up-to-date TeXLive 2013. However it makes no sense to set the second node at (10,0); the frame is only 12cm in the width. But you have some invisible characters in your code (see above). Delete it and try again.

Comment: @Herbert Yes, sorry about that. I just copied the example from the Tikz manual but I actually changed to (3,0) in my example. I tried to delete every possible invisible character and I keep getting at least one question mark there. I use TexShop on Mac OS 10.9, by the way.

Comment: I see strange characters in your code they are those things that the font doesn't have any corresponding characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your code without such invisible characters:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\title{Presentation}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}  
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Basic concepts}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
  \node [concept]                 {Root concept};
  \node [extra concept] at (3,0) {extra concept};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which works well.

Comment: This works indeed. I just could't make it work even after deleting stuff. Thanks!